# check if user already logged in facebook in the app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

i added a facebook login to my app ,
and now when i exit the app i want the user to stil be logged in so to do that i need to check if he is still logged in
i tried to check this way:

```
  public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    return accessToken != null;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work when i exit the app and go back its going to the main page as i was logged in but the user id is not mine i know that cuz the profile picture is empty and not mine anymore,
so how can i check if the user is logged in ?
ty ahead!